# Spring Batch 2.0 DataIntegrityViolationException

Tags: spring-batch

We are facing org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException while trying to insert the data into “BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE” table using spring batch2.0.
This issue does not occurs frequently on our system .It occurs randomly in our test environment. We are using SQL server database server.

Below error message is writing to logs :-

[PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154AB1CB6AD0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (402).; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154AB1CB6AD0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (402).; caused by Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154AB1CB6AD0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (402).] and cannot be retried automatically.  The job must be manually recovered

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154AB1CB6AD0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (402).; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__BATCH_JO__4848154AB1CB6AD0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE'. The duplicate key value is (402).
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:228)
at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:607)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:792)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:850)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:854)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.createJobInstance(

We have also implemented the solution which is mention in below link.

[https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1232?jql=project%2520%253D%2520BATCH%2520AND%2520text%2520~%2520%2522key%2522](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1232?jql=project%2520%253D%2520BATCH%2520AND%2520text%2520%7E%2520%2522key%2522)

We thought it to be a database issue and asked team to recreate the database. Issue is still appearing  after database recreate as well.
We found some details from the spring jira and found that you have worked on similar issues earlier. If you could provide us any insight we will be thankful.

We have done some changes mentioned earlier and none is helping us. If you could provide us with some pointers that will be helpful.

Comment: The stack trace you shared is truncated, please post the full stack trace of the error to see the root cause. Spring Batch v2 is not maintained anymore (as well as v3 BTW). Does this issue happen with the latest v4.3.2? A lot has changed since v2. Please provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: This issue is coming at only one machine . It's not coming each and every time while running the End Of Day Job

Comment: This issue happens because you are trying to insert a row that happens to have a violation of uniqueness. It means that a specific row has the same values with another row in DB. There is a constraint in your table.